# Got Gas Estimation failed error every time, at the time of execution of MultiSig wallet contract. Specifically while executing sendMultiSig() function

Tags: metamask, multisignature

```
function sendMultiSig(
   address toAddress,
   uint value,
   bytes data,
   uint expireTime,
   uint sequenceId,
   bytes signature
) public onlySigner {
// Verify the other signer
var operationHash = keccak256("ETHER", toAddress, value, data, expireTime, sequenceId);

var otherSigner = verifyMultiSig(toAddress, operationHash, signature, expireTime, sequenceId);

// Success, send the transaction
if (!(toAddress.call.value(value)(data))) {
  // Failed executing transaction
  revert();
}
 Transacted(msg.sender, otherSigner, operationHash, toAddress, value, data);
}
```

Contract, which I'm using: https://github.com/BitGo/eth-multisig-v2/blob/master/contracts/WalletSimple.sol

[image]

Comment: There is no gas-estimation in your code (in fact, it is not even a web3-client code, which is what I would expect from a gas-related question).

Comment: ok I am updating my question with this error's screenshot.